# Is there a way to create a Two-Side Button in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, figma

I hope you're all doing well here.
I'm working on developing my first app, and I've created a two-sided button in Figma using a rectangle. I really like the design, and I was wondering if there's a way to recreate it in SwiftUI. As you can see, when I press either "Lyrics" or "Chords," a small "-" should appear below the selected word to indicate which section I'm currently in.

[image]

I couldn't actually create the button the way I wanted it to be. I've been struggling with it and couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is create a cool two-sided button in SwiftUI, just like the one I made in Figma.

Comment: Try, have a look at using a `Picker(...){...}`.pickerStyle(.segmented)`

Comment: "Segmented Control", that's the key word to search for this feature, then look how to customize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this approach using a `Picker` with `.pickerStyle(.segmented)`.
Adjust the looks of it as you see fit.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection = 0
    var body: some View {
        Picker("", selection: $selection) {
            Text("Lyrics").tag(0)
            Text("Chords").tag(1)
        }
        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                    .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2)
            )
        .frame(width: 234)
    }
}
```

You could also use two `Buttons` in a `HStack`, such as:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection = 0
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {selection = 0}) {
                Text("Lyrics").underline(selection == 0)
            }
            Divider()
            Button(action: {selection = 1}) {
                Text("Chords").underline(selection == 1)
            }
        }.frame(width: 160, height: 33)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2))
            .frame(width: 160)
    }
}
```